# Infinite summation with infinite lower limit

Tags: calculus

When will the following equation be correct?
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}f(n,k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{n}f(n,k)
\end{equation}
The problem may be trivial but I cannot claim that it is trivial or nontrivial. Because $f(n, k=n)$ is useful for me, I wanna create it. inf means positive infinity.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why do you write $\sum_{k=n}^nf(n,k)$ instead of just writing $f(n,n)$?

Comment: can we please know under what context you've encountered this problem? Or is it a conceptual doubt?

Comment: Suppose $f(n,k)=1$ for all $n$ and all $k$. Can you see that your equation is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, if $f(n, k)=1$ for all n and k, the equation is incorrect. I think it’s a conceptual question and the question can be whether the lower limit can be infinity nor not in infinite summation. That confuses me...

Comment: I can't see any way to make sense of $\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}f(n)$, so I'd say the lower limit of a summation can't be infinity. $\sum_{n=-\infty}^kf(n)$ can be interpreted in a sensible way, so can $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}f(k,n)$.

Comment: I didn't get your point of 'sensible way'. Could you explain in detail? In my view, the $\lim_{n\rightarrow\inf}\sum_{k=n}^{\inf}f(k. n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\inf}f(n,n)$. But this should be wrong, because I cannot provide any reason to say that.

Comment: Of course it's wrong, jerry. I gave you an example to show that it's wrong, and you agreed that it's wrong. But $\sum_{n=-\infty}^kf(n)$ can be interpreted as $\lim_{r\to-\infty}\sum_{n=r}^kf(n)$, which makes perfect sense. Also, if we let $g(n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}f(k,n)$ (so for example $g(7)$ is $f(7,7)+f(8,7)+\cdots$) then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}f(k,n)$ is just $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)$, again making good sense.

Comment: So where do we stand now?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I’ve understood the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good. Please consider writing up what you now know, and posting it as an answer.